# GAE MapReduce parallelism and quotas

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

Do per minute quotas apply to Google App Engine MapReduce in the same way as they would apply to any non-MapReduce program that simply uses task queues for parallelism or is MapReduce a special kind of implementation of parallelism? [Link to per minute quotas](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Per-minute_Quotas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per-minute quotas no longer exist (please do file a docs bug for that section!), though shorter-than-24-hour quotas do still apply. As @systempuntoout says, the same quotas apply to mapreduces as everything else - they're just ordinary task queue tasks.

Comment: They're both good answers but to hear that "they're just ordinary task queues" takes some uncertainty out of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

MapReduce is not a special kind of implementation of parallelism; it's a fancy and useful framework that, using different Google App Engine APIs like Datastore, Taskqueue and Memcache, implements [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapreduce)-style computations on GAE.

When you run MapReduce jobs, you have the same constraint/quota of any other non-MapReduce tasks; the [quota](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/quota.py) manager framework module helps the mapper to rate limit the execution avoiding to run over quota.